# SQl Server: Isolating data to resolve query msg512 Level 16 issue

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting an error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

when running my query. I know where the conflict is: just trying to determine how to isolate the column in question to resolve the error.

The specific column is called `PARAMETER_SET.TEMPLATE_VERSION`. It has two values. The data in the query below is replicated across the two `template_version` values, which is causing the 512 message (i.e., Merchant, Header3, FID, UID, MID are all replicated).

Note: prior to creating a second `template_version` value and populating the database I was able to run the query below successfully.

My objective is for the query output to contain the data for only one template_version, which should resolve my 512 issue.

```
select 
    t.signature, rp.SIGNATURE as 'estate', 
    tp2.SIGNATURE as 'sub-estate1', 
    tp1.SIGNATURE as 'sub-estate2',  
    (select VALUE 
     from PARAMETER_VALUES pv
     join PARAMETER_SET ps on ps.DATASET_ID = pv.DATASET_ID 
     where FIELD_ID = 'Merchant.1.RcptHdrLn1' 
       and ps.TERMINAL_ID = t.TERMINAL_ID) as 'Merchant1|RcptHdrLn1',
    (select VALUE 
     from PARAMETER_VALUES pv
     join PARAMETER_SET ps on ps.DATASET_ID = pv.DATASET_ID 
     where FIELD_ID = 'Merchant.1.RcptHdrLn2' 
       and ps.TERMINAL_ID = t.TERMINAL_ID) as 'Merchant1|RcptHdrLn2',
    (select VALUE 
     from PARAMETER_VALUES pv
     join PARAMETER_SET ps on ps.DATASET_ID = pv.DATASET_ID 
     where FIELD_ID = 'Merchant.1.Host0|Acq0|Mid' 
       and ps.TERMINAL_ID = t.TERMINAL_ID) as 'Merchant1|Host0|Acq0|Mid',
    (select VALUE 
     from PARAMETER_VALUES pv
     join PARAMETER_SET ps on ps.DATASET_ID = pv.DATASET_ID 
     where FIELD_ID = 'Merchant.1.Fid' and ps.TERMINAL_ID = t.TERMINAL_ID) as 'Merchant1|Fid',
    (select VALUE 
     from PARAMETER_VALUES pv
     join PARAMETER_SET ps on ps.DATASET_ID = pv.DATASET_ID 
     where FIELD_ID = 'Merchant.1.Uid' and ps.TERMINAL_ID = t.TERMINAL_ID) as 'Merchant1|Uid',
    (select VALUE 
     from PARAMETER_VALUES pv
     join PARAMETER_SET ps on ps.DATASET_ID = pv.DATASET_ID 
     where FIELD_ID = 'Header3' and ps.TERMINAL_ID = t.TERMINAL_ID) as 'Header3'
from 
    terminal t 
join 
    terminal tp1 on t.PARENT_ID = tp1.TERMINAL_ID 
join 
    terminal tp2 on tp1.PARENT_ID = tp2.TERMINAL_ID 
join
    terminal rp on tp2.PARENT_ID = rp.TERMINAL_ID 
order by 
    estate, [sub-estate1], [sub-estate2]
```

Comment: Subquery returned more than one value? So add a filter in each subquery: `and ps.Template_Version = '?'` Or if you're sure the values are duplicates you could use a dummy aggregate like `min(Value)` instead.

Comment: Sounds more like a business requirement question than a programming issue. You can resolve by doing TOP 1 or MAX(VALUE) but who knows what the requirements are? Only you.

Comment: yeah...TOP 1.  Not the best solution but can work.  Query can take longer and is not "clean".   I will try min(Value) though....

Comment: I went with the "and ps.template_version =" and that worked.  Don't know how I missed something so simple.   Thanks for the help!